# VC++ linker to remove indirect dependencies for static libraries

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

Consider this scenario (everything in release mode):

```
a.lib includes f1() and f2().
a.lib is built using /LTCG on VS2015.
f1() is local without any external function calls.
f2() calls fc() from b.lib

b.lib includes fc() and 100s of other functions.
b.lib is built by a 3rd party, probably not VS.

main.exe is built only with main.cpp, using /LTCG on VS2015.
main.exe links to a.lib and b.lib
main.cpp only calls f1()
```

Now, when I build main.exe, I expect it to include only f1()'s implementation. The executable size is ~10MB.

However, if I comment out f2()'s implementation in a.lib and rebuilt a.lib, then main.exe becomes 200KB. It works exactly the same in both cases.

My concern is both the size of the executable and exposing anything about b.lib (which is not my own library) unnecessarily.

Question: why is the linker not smart enough to not include f2()->fc() definitions? while it is smart enough to not include the rest of b.lib (which is more than 100MB)?

Comment: Can you experiment with building a.lib using the C/C++ /Gy option and linking your executable using the linker /OPT option?

Comment: /Gy is already defined for a.lib, for executable /OPT:ICF and /OPT:REF are already enabled. Do you have another /OPT in mind?

Answer (score 1):

The linker is dragging in all the statics that `fc` may be using (like a map of error numbers to strings), and all the functions (potentially) called by `fc`, and all the functions that the statics use to initialize themselves.

I wouldn't worry about exposing your use of b.lib (providing you have properly licensed it), protecting the IPR in that is the vendor's problem.

Executable size is a genuine concern, but I don't think there is much you can do about it.

Comment: I know everything related to fc is dragged in, but I don't know why it is necessary, that is my question.
btw, b.lib is properly licensed. But I kinda don't want to ship even its machine code when I don't need to, because we use b.lib for very special products, while a.lib is shared among all our products.

Comment: Without knowing the internals of b.lib, we can't say why it is all needed.

Comment: You say "I kinda don't want to ship even its machine code when I don't need to, because we use b.lib for very special products" but that doesn't make sense to me.  You have a license to use b.lib, use it when you need to - why does it matter to you if some of the machine code is dragged in?

Comment: Are you trying to conceal from your customers you are using b.lib?  I wouldn't bother.

Comment: my reason may not immediately make sense, nonetheless, it is a technical question, and size of the final product really matters in most cases, especially mobile and embedded platforms.
also, how internals of b.lib can affect the linkage of uncalled functions? can you give example?

Comment: I'm sorry but your answer is not really addressing the issue, only rephrasing the problem, so I can't accept it as an answer. I will have to wait someone else.

Comment: I *think* the correct answer is "there is not much you can do about it" - but that doesn't solve the problem, so certainly feel free not to accept it.